# android apps not deployed to phone

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

i just started android development and have the problem that my apps are not deployed to the phone - neither my hello-world nor the examples. after running them i cant find the apps on the emulator and the launch activity is not started either.

i use eclipse with ADT but also tried it via command line.
no errors in the console

any hints?

Comment: Do you see any errors or exceptions in console?

Comment: Can you post AndroidManifest.xml for more details?

Comment: no errors in the console - android manifest: http://pastebin.com/vSv2F6QG

Answer (score 0):

A few things you might want to check are the following:
Is your Android SDK attached to your eclipse.
Is your Android VD Attached to your PROJECT, not just to eclipse.

You need to go to the project->properties and then theres a place where you can attach the AVD and SDK to your project. I don't have eclipse right now to check for you, but If you dont get how tell me and I'll download it and check it for you.

Hope this helps,
kRizD

Comment: i looked at some settings and found out it worked (but only once) if i set the target to be chosen manually in the run configuration. i also tried to change the code to force a rebuild but the apk was only deployed once which seems a bit random to me.. here the console output: http://pastebin.com/0Vrunw2H